# Click image and select radio not working

Tags: html, xhtml

I have this code and cannot get it to select the radio when I click on it's image.

I'm I missing something?

Here is the current code:

```
<label style="display: inline; " for="test1">

<img src="images/image1.jpg" />

<input checked="checked" class="select_control" id="select1" name="test1" type="radio" value="value1" />
</label>

<label style="display: inline; " for="test2">

<img src="images/image2.jpg" />

<input checked="checked" class="select_control" id="select2" name="test2" type="radio" value="value2" />
</label>
```

Comment: The `for` attribute of the `label` must have an id provided not name. Also, I don't think the item with that id should be inside that label.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `for` attribute in label should match input's `id` and not `name`. `name` is used for grouping radio buttons and checkboxes (when it's the same name their are in a group, so checking one will will uncheck the other).

```
<label for="test1">
  <img src="image1.jpg" />
  <input id="test1" name="test" type="radio" value="value1" />
</label>
<label for="test2">
    <img src="image2.jpg" />
    <input id="test2" name="test" type="radio" value="value2" />
</label>
```

Here's a working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/nXb5a/

Answer (score 3):

the for attribute of the label should reference the id of the input it is for not the name 
see: 
http://jsfiddle.net/EtvLu/

Answer (score 1):

the `for` attribute should be the id of the element it is referring to, and both radio buttons should have the same name (assuming you want them as one group):

```
<label style="display: inline; " for="select1">

<img src="images/image1.jpg" />

<input checked="checked" class="select_control" id="select1" name="test1" type="radio" value="value1" />
</label>

<label style="display: inline; " for="select2">

<img src="images/image2.jpg" />

<input checked="checked" class="select_control" id="select2" name="test1" type="radio" value="value2" />
</label>
```